# NodeJS from localhost to online site

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, npm, web-hosting

I have a site that I created using NodeJS and one page html/jquery everything is working as expected on the localhost provided but I'm getting some issue in putting that site online `www.xxxx.com`, I already got a `.com` domain but I don't know which configuration should I do on my site and on code , which mean is there steps to follow on the `app.js` which contain the `localhost:3500` ?

This is the structure of my folder developped under VSCODE

[image: the structure of my folder]

and this is my statement  `app.js` of the localhost

```
//start the server.
app.listen(3500, function () {
 console.log('Example app listening on port 3500!');
});
```

Hope I mentioned everything
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To host a website you don't' just need the domain name (.com)  but you need the server and hosting as well.

Here you can find details:

- Set Up Nginx Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts) on Ubuntu using NGINX (free and open-source)

  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04
- For Windows:

  https://www.rapidvaluesolutions.com/tech_blog/nginx-server-deploying-web-applications/

Comment: is there something on windows ? and for the code part should I do something ?

Comment: Apache for windows, wait let me share url

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/running-nginx-and-apache-for-node-js-phpmyadmin

Comment: Ok thank you so much, I 'm checking them and for the code part is there something that I must do ?

Comment: Yes, @Nodegeek.

Comment: could it be possible to light me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me who doesn't want to get into the configuration details of the host server, check out [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). It's a platform-as-a-service that allows you to host a site really easily and it has a pretty generous free-tier. Not much will have to change code-wise maybe just making the port a variable.

One major issue I had with the platform is that you cannot save files on the filesystem using code, you'll have to use an external file storage like AWS.

The other, slightly minor issue is that you need to be using git to push your code to the heroku servers (Not really an issue tbh since you really should look into git if you aren't using it already)

Comment: I 'm looking into it but the major issue like you mentioned is confusing me,

Comment: @Nodegeek could you clarify what you mean?